# Can I use != and == in C++ for string comparison without writing my own?

Tags: c++, c, string, comparison, string-comparison

What's difference between C and C++ in string comparison in other words?

I came from 'C' camp. I saw program using == to compare strings, I tried to find its overloading program, but did not find one. Does it mean C++ deal with string (char []) naturally with == and !=? 
If I have my own defined String class, would it be same that I can use == and != without defining them? or it applies only to char []? 
 
Edit: 
It looks like I mixed C's char[] with C++ std::string class. OK, the old question still apply. Some followed questions as below:
My programs defined char[] variables, but compared with "==" operator. It seemed work. They are C-style string, but work with "==". Did compiler auto-convert them to std::string for me so that the programs worked?
Edit2:
Here is a working sample.

```
if(name == "") return;
```

where "name" is a MyString class item. It has a construtor with a parameter char*. 
MyString has a public function data(), it returns char* C-style string pointer.
So, am I comparing MyString objects? or C-style strings?
Without overload "!=" myself, can I do something like below?

```
if( name.data() != somes_[i].data() )
....
```

Comment: Just for reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Comment: It doesn't deal with it naturally, if the string is implemented as a class it has to implement operator== to handle this comparison.  Use std::string, which has this defined for you.

Comment: Are you sure it was comparing `char*` or `char[]` and not `std::string`? If so, I would be curious to see the code.

Comment: @crashmstr: Since I came from 'C', no idea diff between char[] and std::string. Aren't they same?

Comment: @Tim `char[]` didn't change from C to C++ it's still just `char *` fundamentally, whereas `std::string` is a class that encapsulates a C style string.

Comment: @Tim: *"My programs defined char[] variables, but cmopared with "==" operator. It seemed work. They are C-style string, but work with "==""* ~> show us the code you used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*"Does it mean C++ deal with string (`char []`) naturally with `==` and `!=`?"*

**No**. It is wrong to compare C-style strings (i.e. `char[]` or `char*`) between each other with `==` or `!=` (in both C and C++), because you will end up comparing pointers rather than strings.

In C++ it is possible to compare [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) object with a C-style string or another [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) object because of the `std::string`'s [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) and [`operator!=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp):

```
std::string str1("abc"), str2("def");
if (str1 != str2 && str1 == "abc")
    std::cout << "Yep, I got it.";
```

Comment: Do I need to explicitly declare at least one std::string item to apply for using "==" and "!=" comparison operators? What if one of them is something like "a string"?

Comment: @Tim: Yes. One of the compared values must be an instance of `std::string`.

Answer (score 6):

> Does it mean C++ deal with string (char []) naturally with == and !=?

No; `"aaa" == "aaa"` will convert the string literals to `char*` as normal, and compare the pointer values. However most implementations of C and C++ will de-duplicate string literal data, at least within an object file, so that those pointers will be the same. This is not guaranteed by the standard, but is widely implemented.

In other words, C++ does not differ from C in this regard and comparing `char*` values this way is no better than doing so in C.

> Did compiler auto-convert them to std::string for me so that the programs worked?

`std::string` has overloaded comparison operators that work with `char*`. If you compare a `char*` with an `std::string` then one of those will be used.

```
char const *s = "aaa";
std::string t = "aaa";
s == t; // uses overloaded operator== to compare string values.
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

```
template< class CharT, class traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==( const CharT* lhs, const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs );
```

Comment: The fact that you can get away with it on some compilers is a very bad reason to suggest using it.  This is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @DaleWilson I'm not sure who you think is recommending it.

Comment: A lot of programmers will interpret "This is not guaranteed by the standard but is widely implemented." as "Try it and if it works, you are OK."   I know this because I have spent a lot of my life fixing nasty bugs written by such programmers.   I'll undo my down vote, because you are answering the question, but nonetheless any time you say "this is questionable but it works" it would be a very good idea to add "so please, don't ever use it."

Answer (score 0):

Do not use != or != to compare C-style strings (char * or char[]).

If you are sure the strings are null terminated use std::strcmp().  If you aren't absolutely 100% POSITIVE that they are null terminated, use std::strncmp() to compare them.

if either of your strings is an std::string you can use operator == or operator !=.

[edited in response to comment from barnes53]

Comment: This simply lists ways of comparing strings without answering the question.

Comment: The question "Can I use != and == to compare [C-style] strings?"  My answer: "No, (but you can use this approach instead.)"

Comment: Is "" (or something like "word") considered as a std::string?

Comment: No,it's a literal char *.  A pointer to a null terminated c-style string.