# Reading user input from std::cin.get

Tags: c++, validation, std, user-input

i have created a DLL that opens a console and read the inputs of a user..

Now i got a problem with reading the input of a user and when the input is an value that is listed with an function the code calls the function..

Here is my code:

```
void UserTest::Menu() {
char UserInput[256];

centerstring(" <<- Functions ->>\n\n");

centerstring("<<-  VEHICLE  ->>\n");
centerstring("<<-  KEYBIND  ->>\n");
centerstring("<<-  EXECUTE  ->>\n");
centerstring("<<-  CLEAR    ->>\n");

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.sync();

std::cin.get(UserInput, 256);

if (UserInput == "CLEAR"){
    UserTest::ClearConsole();
    UserTest::Menu();
}else{
    if (UserInput == "VEHICLE"){
        centerstring("<<-  VEHICLE    ->>\n");

        UserTest::PreCallVehicle(UserInput);
    }else{
        if (UserInput == ("EXECUTE")){
            centerstring("<<-  SCRIPT    ->>\n");

            UserTest::PreCallScript(UserInput);
        }else{
            if (UserInput == "KEYBIND"){
                centerstring("<<-  KEYBINDS    ->>\n\n\n");

                UserTest::PreCallKeybind();
            }else{
                UserTest::ClearConsole();
                centerstring("<<-  ERROR    ->>\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When i type VEHICLE or any other listed string in the console i get centerstring("<<-  ERROR    ->>\n")..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use != and == in C++ for string comparison without writing my own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232814/can-i-use-and-in-c-for-string-comparison-without-writing-my-own)

Answer (score 2):

The error is using operator== to compare two char*. While this compiles, it certainly does not what you expect it to do, since it compares value of the pointer, rather than the string.

To do proper comparison, either use std::string, or, if you must use raw C-style strings, use srncmp().

Comment: surely this is a duplicate and should be closed as such.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I have no problem with that :)